# How can I set MongoDB's path with the C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I currently run MongoDB pointing to the appropriate data directory using the command line below:

```
mongod --dbpath "somePath/data"
```

But currently this is a manual step that I run before running a particular suite of tests. Is there a way I can set the path within the code (without calling a script or batch file) using the Mongo C# driver to use a specific data directory?

**Update**:

To clarify, the reason I'm looking to do this isn't for use in production code, but to isolate test databases for different test suites and to point at a disposable and isolated data directory so that each server instance is clean at the time of running tests and is only populated with the data it requires for the same server settings as production.

Comment: Totally agreed with @displayName. Your `mongod` server must be up and running. Consider [install mongo as windows service](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb).

Answer (score 3):

You probably won't find any way to do that. The Mongo C# Driver is for programming a MongoClient, not a server. The documentation for C# Driver for MongoDB says - `MongoClient class serves as the root object for working with a MongoDB server`. When you are programming a client, you automatically would assume that the server is up and running. Whether you do it manually or you write another code for it, that is a different story.

Very rarely would you allow people to connect to a machine and let them start a server **AND A CLIENT** on it. And why is it rare? You may try to start a server *on another machine* and screw up with that machine (which may be providing some other completely different service too!). There are some ways (and there are times when it is needed) to start a server remotely, but that is not what you can do using the MongoDB C# Driver.

Now, in order to get your task done, you can try this:

Start one mongod per database on your server, and make each mongod listen to a different port. Then in your code, you can connect your MongoClient to mongod running on the concerned database's port. You can achieve this by using a simple if condition (or a switch case) and checking what database the MongoClient wants to connect to and thus finding the right port value to put in the connection string. Each mongod can serve only one database or more or whatever you want.

So if you are running three `mongod`'s on port1, port2 and port3 and all those three are connected to their respective db paths, the code can be somewhat like this:

```
var DBNAME = name_of_the_db;
string connectionString;

switch (DBNAME)
{
    case name_of_first_DB:
        connectionString = "mongodb://[user:pass@]hostname[:port1][/[DBNAME][?options]]";
        break;
    case name_of_second_DB:
        connectionString = "mongodb://[user:pass@]hostname[:port2][/[DBNAME][?options]]";
        break;
    case name_of_third_DB:
        connectionString = "mongodb://[user:pass@]hostname[:port3][/[DBNAME][?options]]";
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid DB Name");
}
```

**Answering the updated part of the question:**
You can start `mongod`'s on different partitions of the server. Even start the daemons from different drives altogether and make them listen to different ports. Goes without saying that the dbpaths should not be pointing to the same drive for any two databases to at least pretty closely mimic what you wanted.

Just to complete this answer I am adding what @Schaliasos has mentioned in comments.. Consider [installing mongo as a window service](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb).

Comment: Thanks for the answer (I want to vote it up, but I don't have enough reputation at the moment). I'll update the question as well, but just to clarify, the reason I'm looking to do this isn't for use in production code, but to isolate test databases for different test suites to point at a disposable and isolated data directory so that each server instance is clean at the time of running tests and only populated with the data it requires for the same server settings as production. If this isn't possible, I'll opt for different databases in each suite's config instead.